# Restful PUT acting as GET when testing

Tags: c#, rest, get, put

So I've been working on an api that, using RESTful, allows the user to get data from a database. Pretty simple, URL is along the lines of local:port/projects/[id of project]. The api returns some xml with 4 or 5 results.

What I'm having trouble with is PUT. As far as I understand it, I should use the same url, but use the PUT request method, and include the data that I want sent in a parameter. The problem seems to be that when I run the PUT, it just returns the same data as a GET.

I'm using the following site to test this: wst dot mytechlabs dot com (won't let me post two links here;?)

The code for my controller is located here: http://pastebin.com/3HXXR4YY

Thanks in advance, I'll monitor this, so let me know if I forgot any info that would help.

Comment: Please include the relevant code and **only the relevant code** in your question.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I put the entire code here is I'm pretty new at this(can you tell by my single bronze medal?). Last time I posted what I thought was all the relevant code, I had a bunch of people tell me to post the entire controller. So I thought I would just skip that step. Sorry.